# Windows 7 no sound in video

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, audio, drivers, video

I have Windows 7 SP1 on my Lenovo Thinkpad T530. I had default sound drivers from Microsoft installed with Win7 and it worked OK, except the sound was low. I installed Realtek drivers from Lenovo site and now I have an issue, when playing audio or video from browser - i have the sound and it's louder than it was before, but now I don't have audio when playing video files from my computer.

What I have done:

I have reinstalled the codec packs, reinstalled the drivers several times, cleaned all previous drivers with driver sweeper, tried several players and other codec packs - nothing has changed - sound is in the browser but not when starting video with some player. I tried also to change configurations in the player to set different output devices - but everything is the same, although output device is selected correctly.

As a solution I could rollback to default windows driver, but I want to know how to resolve such issues, where to look, what tools to use, etc.

Drivers seems OK, cause I have windows 8 on another hdd for the same laptop and when I booted there I checked driver version, etc - it's the same, but on windows 8 sound works OK everywhere.

Comment: Seems like i explained that i've tried lots of things including different players: vlc, media player classic, windows media player. There is only one sound card in my laptop, nothing was muted, etc.

Comment: What codec is the audio in? You can use MediaInfo to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used DFX Audio Enhancer and it fixed my problem, although it's not the solution I was trying to get, but at least it fixed the issue.

To all the comments above: this was not a simple issue, I think I had some driver compatibility issue, or smth like that.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit "simple", but have you checked the configuration from the audio-output?(**loudspeaker-symbol -> rightclick -> mixer**) Is it possible that one of the sliders is off? Because there you can change the loudness from the different sounds(flash, ie, firefox etc.)

Comment: yes, of course i checked it. it's ok. I am experienced user, and i wouldn't have posted such question without checking everything several times. I have been struggling with this issue for couple of days.

Comment: Sometimes one can overlook the simplest thing. Even after struggling for several days.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it's not my case. From the question itself it's obvious that it's not possible that the reason is this "simple thing". Cause I explained that I have tried everything I know, so i asked about some advanced methods of troubleshooting.